# Neumann Boundary Condition for thermal radiation between two bodies

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, heat-equation

I'm trying to formulate and solve a pde which models thermal radiation between two bodies using a Neumann boundary condition.

I've created a mesh and want to capture the thermal radiation heat transfer between element 106 and element 19 in the boundary mesh wireframe plot below.

[image]

I've modelled convective BCs as follows:

```
GconvPistComb = NeumannValue[hPistComb*(TPistHeat - temp[z, r]), ElementMarker == 106];
GconvBlkCool = NeumannValue[hCoolWater1*(TWater1 - temp[z, r]), ElementMarker == 75]
```

The pde with just these included looks like:

```
pde = {1/r D[-kMesh r D[temp[z, r], r], r] + D[-kMesh D[temp[z, r], z], 
 z] == GconvPistComb + GconvBlkCool
```

If I were modelling the thermal radiation from ambient gas to element 19 I would use the following Neumann BC in which TAmb is a pre-defined fixed value:

```
GradAmbTest = 
  NeumannValue[Epsilon Sigma (TAmb - temp[z, r])^4, 
   ElementMarker == 19];
```

How can I replace TAmb with an expression that represents the solved temperature field for Element 106?

Comment: There are a number of definitions missing from this code, so without having that, it seems that your question is either: 1) how to replace `TAmb` in the definition of `GradAmbTest` or 2) how to actually calculate what it is you want to replace `TAmb` with. In the case of 1), is it possible you can use something like `ReplaceAll` or write it as a function of `TAmb`? If 2), then it seems you could benefit from explaining what exactly it is that you want to calculate, and if this is not known by you, it might help to ask on something like the physics SE. I am not sure, though. Can you clarify?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's 1) - in the expression for GradAmbTest I'd like to calculate the difference between the temperature fields at Element 106 and Element 19, raise it to the power of 4 and multiply by the emissivity (Epsilon) and Stefan Boltzmann Constant (Sigma) to obtain the thermal radiation from Element 106 to Element 19.

Comment: Have you tried something like TAmb -> temp[0.37,r]?

Comment: It would be very useful if you could give a complete specification of the model you have so that people can try and experiment.

Comment: Did you figure this out?